# how to get the current row index with Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I wrote a Python script to extract some string values from a .json file, store them in some dictionnary and fill them in an .xlsx file using Openpyxl, which I use for the 1st time:

in short, it looks like that :

```
WORKBOOK = Workbook()
WORKSHEET = WORKBOOK.active
. . .
. . .
for PERSON in TEAM_LIST:
    for ITEM in ITEMS[PERSON]:
       if PERSON in REGULAR_LIST:
          PERSON_ITEMS_ROW = (PERSON,ITEM[0],ITEM[1],ITEM[2],ITEM[3],ITEM[4)]
          SHEET.append(PERSON_ITEMS_ROW)    # Fill each row with some PERSON ITEMS
      else:
        PERSON_ITEMS_ROW = (PERSON,ITEM[0],ITEM[1],ITEM[2],ITEM[5],ITEM[6])
        SHEET.append(PERSON_ITEMS_ROW)      # Fill each row with other PERSON ITEMS
```

This code works well (although I am not 100% sure it is correct)

I would like to change backgroud and foreground color of rows selected in the "else" part above, and I don't manage to find a way to do it ;

I know how to apply specific color and font to a specific row : I do it for the 1st row used as the header row, but I don't know how to get the current row index so I could apply specific color and font on each row of "else" section

Any idea is welcome

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `ws._current_row`.
**Note**: `ws._current_row` are only valid after inserting new cells.

You can do it for instance:

```
    ...
    SHEET.append(PERSON_ITEMS_ROW)
    # For all cells in ws._current_row
    for row_cells in ws.iter_rows(min_row=ws._current_row,  max_row=ws._current_row):
        for cell in row_cells:
            cell.font = Font(color=colors.GREEN, italic=True)

    # Only for cell in column A == 1
    ws.cell(row=ws._current_row, column=1).font = Font(color=colors.RED)
```

---

If you **don't want** to use unsupported `ws._current_row`.

```
    # Assume you start in row==2
    for ws_current_row, PERSON in enumerate(TEAM_LIST, 2):
        #...
        #SHEET.append(PERSON_ITEMS_ROW)

        # For all cells in ws_current_row
        for row_cells in ws.iter_rows(min_row=ws_current_row, max_row=ws_current_row):
            for cell in row_cells:
                cell.font = Font(color=colors.GREEN, italic=True)

        # Only for cell in column A == 1
        ws.cell(row=ws_current_row, column=1).font = Font(color=colors.RED)
```

---

OOP solution, or `openpyxl` could implemented it.
For instance:

```
    from openpyxl.workbook.workbook import Workbook as _Workbook
    from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet as _Worksheet

    class Worksheet(_Worksheet):
        # Overload openpyxl.Worksheet.append
        def append(self, iterable):
            super().append(iterable)
            return self._current_row, \
                   self._cells_by_col(min_col=1, min_row=self._current_row,
                                      max_col=self.max_column, max_row=self._current_row)

    class Workbook(_Workbook):
        # Workaround, as openpyxl is not using self.create_sheet(...) in __init__
        def __init__(self, write_only=True):
            super().__init__(write_only)
            self.__write_only = False
            self.create_sheet()

        # Not working for self.read_only and self.write_only :
        # Overload openpyxl.Workbook.create_sheet
        def create_sheet(self, title=None, index=None):
            new_ws = Worksheet(parent=self, title=title)
            self._add_sheet(sheet=new_ws, index=index)
            return new_ws

    for PERSON in TEAM_LIST:
        # ...
        ws_current_row, iter_col = SHEET.append(PERSON_ITEMS_ROW)

        # Iterate all cells from generator iter_col
        for cell in [col_cells[0] for col_cells in iter_col]:
            cell.font = Font(color=colors.RED, italic=True)

        # Only for cell in column A == 1
        ws.cell(row=ws_current_row, column=1).font = Font(color=colors.BLUE)
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1 - LibreOffice: 4.3.3.2***
[OpenPyXL Documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/)

Comment: thanks for this reply, 
it works ! 
(btw, there is a typo in the 2nd ws.current_row, "_" missing)

   Related question : where can I find documentation or, better, some samples explaining the usage of such options/attributes/methods as "_current_row" ? 
Openpyxl is very powerful, but I have got some difficulties to find clear explanations of simple cases as the one I have started to write; many scripts examples show rows, columns,  cells values hard-coded in the python script, but no so many with values obtained thru variables as I did;
well, maybe, I did not search enough ... ;-)

Comment: can't find a way to do line breaks on comments above : Shit+Enter seemed to work when editing, but I see it disappeared ...

Comment: @bigstyx: Added a link to the docs to the bottom of my Answer. The best Source to get such info are Stackoverflow.

Comment: I strongly advise against using private attributes in code like this. They can change without warning at any time.

Comment: The best place to ask questions about the openpyxl documentation is the openpyxl mailing list. http://groups.google.com/group/openpyxl-users

Comment: So complex answer cannot be good. I didn't downvote yours, but answer from @CharlieClark below is the best one there

Answer (score 18):

I would like to share an easy solution for obtaining the row number while iterating over rows using the `ws.iter_rows()` method. I'm using the first object from the row tuple, which is a cell, so it also has information about its row and column.

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=ws.max_rows):
    print('Row number:', str(row[0].row))
```

Comment: Note that this does not seem to work if that first cell is an `EmptyCell`.

Comment: Bruno's comment is correct, don't use this for empty rows.

Answer (score 3):

My sugguestion is below:

```
for index, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=ws.max_row)):
    print(index)
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Except for its own internal use, openpyxl has no concept of the "current" row. In your case I suspect `ws.max_row` is what you want.

Comment: Totally agree. When you append row-by-row to a new sheet, your last row where values were set is `ws.max_row`